# Additional htaccess rule to remove .php extension doesn't work for wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress blog where we already have the following htaccess code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now i want to add another rule to remove .php extension from a specific URL.

Say. we have abc.com/def/ghi.php

I want a rule to ignore .php extension for this specific url. I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
RewriteRule ^(def)/(ghi)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: you need to move it up to the top of your rules

Comment: @cmorrissey is right. the `[L]`-flag means last rule, so if WP-index is matched, no other rules are processed.

Comment: Also this rule will internally call the script `/def.php`...

Comment: @cmorrissey I replaced it to the top but still no luck. Can you please post the updated code as an answer?

Comment: @arkascha Can you please rectify the code and post as an answer?

Comment: `$1` references the _first_ capture group, so the _first_ colon group.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct regex of your `.php` adding rule and keep it just before WP's front controller rule:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(def|ghi)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php

</IfModule>    
# END WordPress
```